# Reusable storage for array of objects V4

Tags: c++, array, memory-management, pointers, type-safety

Here is a thirdfollow up on [Reusable storage for array of objects](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286755/reusable-storage-for-array-of-objects), [Reusable storage for array of objects V2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286856/reusable-storage-for-array-of-objects-v2) and  [Reusable storage for array of objects V3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286869/reusable-storage-for-array-of-objects-v3), taking into account the provided answers.
The following code should be compliant at least with `gcc`, `clang`, `msvc` and for C++14 and beyond.
In this version, I leave only the core code for lisibility and provide a [testbench](https://godbolt.org/z/njPe5r98s) on Compiler Explorer.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
// @ adding forgotten cstdlib
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <new>
#include <type_traits>

// type-punning reusable buffer
// holds a non-typed buffer (actually a char*) that can be used to store any
// types, according to user needs
class Buffer {
   private:
    // destructing functor storage
    // required to call the correct object destructors
    void (*Destructors)(Buffer*) noexcept = nullptr;
    // storage address
    unsigned char* Storage = nullptr;
    // objects address
    unsigned char* Objects = nullptr;
    // number of stored elements
    std::size_t CountOfStoredObjects = 0;
    // buffer size in bytes
    std::size_t StorageSizeInBytes = 0;

    // computes the smallest positive offset in bytes that must be applied to
    // Storage in order to have alignment a Alignment is supposed to be a valid
    // alignment
    static std::size_t OffsetForAlignment(unsigned char const* const Ptr,
                                          std::size_t Alignment) noexcept {
        std::size_t Res = static_cast<std::size_t>(
            reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(Ptr) % Alignment);
        if (Res) {
            return Alignment - Res;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

   public:
    // allocates a char buffer large enough for Counts object of type T and
    // default-construct them
    template <typename T>
    T* DefaultAllocate(const std::size_t Count) {
        if (Count > (std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() - alignof(T)) /
                        sizeof(T)) {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }
        // Destroy previously stored objects
        if (Destructors) {
            Destructors(this);
        }
        std::size_t RequiredSize = sizeof(T) * Count + alignof(T);
        if (StorageSizeInBytes < RequiredSize) {
            // Creating a storage of RequiredSize bytes
            unsigned char* NewStorage = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(
                std::realloc(Storage, RequiredSize));
            if (NewStorage == nullptr) {
                throw std::bad_alloc();
            }
            Storage = NewStorage;
            StorageSizeInBytes = RequiredSize;
        }
        unsigned char* AlignedStorage =
            Storage + OffsetForAlignment(Storage, alignof(T));
        // initializing an dynamic array of T on the storage
        T* Tmp = ::new (AlignedStorage) T[Count];
        Objects = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(Tmp);
        // update nb of objects
        CountOfStoredObjects = Count;

        // create destructors functor
        Destructors = [](Buffer* PBuffer) noexcept {
            PBuffer->Destructors = nullptr;
            T* ToDestruct = reinterpret_cast<T*>(PBuffer->Objects);
            // Delete elements in reverse order of creation
            while (PBuffer->CountOfStoredObjects > 0) {
                --(PBuffer->CountOfStoredObjects);
                ToDestruct[(PBuffer->CountOfStoredObjects)].~T();
            }
            ::operator delete[](ToDestruct, ToDestruct);
            PBuffer->CountOfStoredObjects = 0;
            PBuffer->Objects = nullptr;
        };
        return Tmp;
    }

    ~Buffer() noexcept {
        // Ending objects lifetime
        if (Destructors) {
            Destructors(this);
        }
        // Releasing storage
        std::free(Storage);
    }
};
```

[EDIT] pinpointing fixes with `// @ ...` and replacing ```std::function``` by a simplier function pointer

Comment: Sorry if I missed some, I thought I did. Give me time to go other it again. I will post a comment when I'm done.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I'm utterly sorry, I didn't find what issue I may have forgotten (perhaps I didn't fix them correctly). I made an edit to pinpoint where I addressed the mentioned problems. Btw I also managed to remove ```std::function```. I had an issue with msvc/C++14 that was merely due to a missing compiler option.